# Angular 2 Facebook Login

Tags: javascript, facebook, typescript, angular

I am developing an website that needs to be logged in with Facebook account. I am using Angular 2 and, of course, TypeScript. It works But not exactly what I wanted. I can't take back the user's information.

Let's go to the code:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Main} from './pages/main/main';

declare const FB: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.html',
  directives: [Main]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit { 

token: any;
loged: boolean = false;
user = { name: 'Hello' };

constructor() { }

statusChangeCallback(response: any) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        console.log('connected');
    } else {
        this.login();
    }
}

login() {
    FB.login(function(result) {
        this.loged = true;
        this.token = result;
    }, { scope: 'user_friends' });
}

me() {
    FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,first_name,gender,picture.width(150).height(150),age_range,friends',
        function(result) {
            if (result && !result.error) {
                this.user = result;
                console.log(this.user);
            } else {
                console.log(result.error);
            }
        });
}

ngOnInit() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(response => {
        this.statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
}
}
```

Basically, When the page loads I check if the user is logged in to Facebook, if not, I call the login method. The *me* method is used to fetch the users information, like its name, first name etc. When I logged in condition browser console print the following line:

```
Object {id: "666", name: "Paulo Henrique Tokarski Glinski", first_name: "Paulo", gender: "male", picture: Object…}
```

Everything ok! But I want to get that Object and put into a User object! Something like that:

***me method***:

```
this.user = result;    
console.log(this.user);
```

But the user just exists inside the method. If I print it outside, its returns nothing.
I just want to print the users name etc. at the website page. I did almost the same thing with Angular JS and worked well.

Please! Help me!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use fat arrow functions to use the same context ...

```
login() {
  FB.login((result: any) => {
    this.loged = true;
    this.token = result;
  }, { scope: 'user_friends' });
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, but now I have other question. I can get and put the result in my `user` var, but I need to do something, like a button click, to refresh the result in my page.I am also using the arrow function in my `me()` method.

Comment: yes , you need to use ngZone to solve this problem ...
please refer to https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/NgZone-class.html

if you still need more help you can reply ...

Answer (score 3):

For the facebook javascript SDK, You just add the following line in your index.html

```
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
```

and in ngOnInit()  :

```
    `FB.init({
        appId      : 'your-app-id',
        cookie     : false, 
        xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
        version    : 'v2.5' // use graph api version 2.5
    });`
```

Answer (score 3):

Angular 2 Service level implementation

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions,URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { ConfigService } from "app/core/services/config.service";

import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; 
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

   constructor(private http: Http,
               private configProvider:ConfigService) {
    }
    authenticateFacebook(){
         window.location.href = 'https://www.facebook.com/v2.9/dialog/oauth?client_id='+
         this.configProvider.config.facebook.clientId + 
         '&redirect_uri='+ this.configProvider.config.facebook.redirectURI + '&scope=public_profile';
    }
    getAccessToken(authenticationCode: string){
        var authProviderUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/oauth/access_token';
        var authParameters = {
            client_id: this.configProvider.config.facebook.clientId,
            redirect_uri: this.configProvider.config.facebook.redirectURI,
            client_secret: this.configProvider.config.facebook.clientSecret,
            code: authenticationCode
        };
        var params = [];
        for (var k in authParameters) {
            params.push(k + '=' + authParameters[k]);
        }
        var authOpenURI = authProviderUrl + '?' + params.join('&');

         return this.http.get(authOpenURI)
                   .map(res => res.json())
                   .catch(err => Observable.throw(err));
    }
    getUserFacebookProfile(accessToken:string):Observable<any>{
        var fields = ['id', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'link', 'name','picture.type(small)'];
        var graphApiUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me?fields=' + fields.join(',');

        return this.http.get(graphApiUrl+'&access_token='+accessToken+'')
                   .map(res => res.json())
                   .catch(err => Observable.throw(err)); 
    }
```

Caller level function, this code will be in the component of your redirect URI

```
//Facebook authentication check
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("code") > -1){
      var code = window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.indexOf("?") + 1).split('&')[0].split('=')[1];
      this.getFaceBookProfile(code);
    }
    //Get profile from facebook
    getFaceBookProfile(code:string){
      this.authService.getAccessToken(code).subscribe(oathAccessData => {
        this.authService.getUserFacebookProfile(oathAccessData.access_token).subscribe(profile => {
           this.userProfile = new UserProfile(profile.name,profile.email, profile.picture.data.url,"facebook",
           profile.id);},err => { console.log(err); });},err => { console.log(err);});

                  this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);     
    }
```

Comment: It looks like your configProvider has the facebook clientSecret? Not really a good idea to keep that in the front-end.

Answer (score 0):

`this` has a bunch of magic involved. Does it help if you capture the class's `this` in a variable and use *that* in the callbacks (so as to avoid caring what *their* `this` is)?

e.g.

```
login() {
    var self = this;
    FB.login(function(result) {
        self.loged = true;
        self.token = result;
    }, { scope: 'user_friends' });
}
```

Comment: i would not use the old self/that workaround anymore. arrow functions are the way to go for this, or bind(this). since it is an anonymous functions, i would go for an arrow function.

Comment: Sure, if you don't care if it works on IE — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions — I wasn't even sure that was the OP's entire problem so I thought I'd just give am example.

Comment: he is using ES6 (like every serious js developer nowadays), so he is most likely using babel to transpile his code to ES5. no problem with IE. no one uses ES6 without a transpiler (i guess).