# Angular 2 Facebook Authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, angular, passport.js

I´m triying to implement facebook authenticathion from my angular 2 app but I think I'm implenting in the wrong way and I can't find some tutorials about this and also I want to ask if ¿is Auth0 the only way to implement this?. 
Well I have this:

Node JS server :

```
//  FB authentication
authRoutes.get('/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { session : false, scope: ['email'] }))
authRoutes.get('/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', { session : false, failureRedirect: '/'}), ctrlAuthentication.facebookResponse)
```

these are the routes in the api and I'm using passportjs, all works when I call the api directly in the browser like: localhost:3000/api/auth/facebook and I get the user returned from the api in JSON format.

Now in the front I have angular 2 and this is
authentication.service.ts:

```
import {User} from '../_models/user'

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
public token : String;
public user : User;

constructor(private http: Http){
}

fbLogin() : Observable<User> {
    let user = this.http.get('/api/auth/facebook')
        .map(this.mapUser);
    return user;
 }

mapUser(response : Response) : User {
    console.log(response)
    let data = response.json();
    this.token = data.token;
    let user = <User>(data.user);
    this.user = user;

    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ user: user, token: data.token }));
    return user;
}
}
```

and this is the register.component.ts:

```
import {AuthenticationService} from '../_services/authentication.service'
import {User} from '../_models/user'

@Component({
  selector: 'crowd-register',
  templateUrl: 'app/RegisterComponent/register.component.html'
})

export class RegisterComponent {
private user : User;
constructor(
    private authenticationService : AuthenticationService
) {}

fbLogin() {
    this.authenticationService.fbLogin().subscribe(
        user => {
            this.user = user;
        }
     )
 }


}
```

When I call fbLogin() from the app I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
MapSubscriber.AuthenticationService.mapUser [as project] (authentication.service.ts:46)
```

I think this is because I'm don't getting the user from my api, I'm getting the response from facebook and this isn't executing or something.

[This is the picture of the console.log(response) and the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSLfp.png)

Thanks for all answers, sorry for my english.

Comment: What does `console.log(response)` print? Also, what is User? an interface or a class?

Comment: It prints: _body: whit html code, ok: true, status: 200, statusText: OK and url: with a facebook url, I think this is the page that should render for authorize application in facebook page but it doesn't render,  and User is a class that containes _id, email, role and profile, I build this structure in the api and send like response.

Comment: is there any **user** property in the response object? because that's where the relevant stuff should happen :)

Comment: I added an image about response, this don´t have any property about user. Thanks for answer!

Comment: I think you should use the facebook authentication api, I'm not sure what you are expecting, but you likely are not getting the desired answer. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37770471/angular-2-facebook-login

Comment: You can not call the FB login dialog via AJAX in the background (for the obvious security reasons.)